# Let widget silently overflow outside screen

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

How can I make a widget (`MarkdownBody`) in a `ListView` silently overflow horizontally outside the screen if the content is too long to fit on the screen?

I've tried using `ClipPath`, `OverflowBox` and a few other solutions, but I couldn't get any of them to do what I want to do. No matter what I try, either the `MarkdownBody` wraps its content to two lines or I get an overflow error.

Is there a way to simply make the widget silently overflow and paint itself outside the screen without generating overflow errors?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the widget is only horizontally overflowing then you may put the `MarkdownBody` inside a `SingleChildScrollView` with `scrollDirection` set to `Axis.horizontal`

Comment: Thanks, this works like a charm. I have nested two `SingleChildScrollable` because I have multiple `MarkdownBody` in a list. The inner one has `scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal` and `physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics()`, while the outer one has `scrollDirection: Axis.vertical`. Also, each `MarkdownBody` is wrapped in a `Row` (which are the children of the inner `SingleChildScrollview`).